# Why doesn't ReentrantLock lock in a Jenkins Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, concurrency, jenkins-pipeline, java.util.concurrent

I cannot seem to get this concurrence pattern to work in my Jenkins Pipeline script as intended. I have simplified the scenario as much as possible and the result still makes no sense. Here is the entire Jenkinsfile:

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock

// create lock and index vars to make sure concurrent threads write different output files
shellLock = new ReentrantLock()
shellIndex = 0

def doIt() {
    shellLock.lock()
    def threadShellIndex = ++shellIndex
    if (threadShellIndex == 1) {
        sh("rm -rf shell")
        sh("mkdir shell")
    }
    shellLock.unlock()

    sh "touch shell/${threadShellIndex}"
}

node {
    checkout scm
    runs = [
        "1": { doIt() },
        "2": { doIt() },
    ]
    parallel runs
}
```

This does not, as I expect, remove and replace the "shell" directory before both runs proceed to create a file in it. Instead, the console output is:

```
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] { (Branch: 1)
[Pipeline] { (Branch: 2)
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] sh
[1] + rm -rf shell
[Pipeline] sh
[2] + touch shell/2
touch: cannot touch ‘shell/2’: No such file or directory
[Pipeline] }
Failed in branch 2
[1] + mkdir shell
[Pipeline] }
Failed in branch 1
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Also:   hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 1
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.handleExit(DurableTaskStep.java:658)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.check(DurableTaskStep.java:604)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.run(DurableTaskStep.java:548)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.tryRelease(ReentrantLock.java:151)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.release(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1261)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.unlock(ReentrantLock.java:457)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1111.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1125)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:163)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:157)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:161)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:165)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.doIt(WorkflowScript:14)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:22)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:86)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(FunctionCallBlock.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor109.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:400)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

How do I get run 2 to wait until run 1 has recreated the directory?

Comment: Try to use "lockable resources" plugin instead which provides a `lock` step. Often, low-level code like shown doesn't work correctly in CPS-transformed script. Sometimes you can work around using `@NonCPS`, but in this case you are calling shell steps, which cannot be called from `@NonCPS` annotated methods.

Comment: @zett42 Thanks, but I don't want a lock across the entire server (in my real case, I actually have a _lot_ of jobs that use this code). I just want it local to a run of the job. I suppose I could lock something specific to the job, but that still feels like an ugly hack especially went most of the time this won't run in parallel. And this seems like it ought to work, or there ought to be an explanation why not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the reason `ReentrantLock` has no effect is that pipeline groovy doesn't actually multithread. It uses a single thread to host multiple "green" threads.

From https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin:

> All program logic is run inside a “CPS VM thread”, which is just a Java thread pool that can run binary methods and figure out which continuation to do next. The parallel step uses “green threads” (also known as coöperative multitasking): it records logical thread (~ branch) names for various actions, but does not literally run them simultaneously.

Since all calls are in the same thread, `ReentrantLock` re-enters.

In my case, I was able to get around the need to lock with the use of [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#incrementAndGet--) and some symlink cleverness around re-creating the directory.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger
shellCounter = new AtomicInteger()

@NonCPS
def getNextShellCounter() {
    return shellCounter.incrementAndGet()
}

...

    def threadShellIndex = getNextShellCounter()

    // concurrency-safe creation of output dir and removal of previous
    def shellDir = "shell.${currentBuild.number}"
    sh """#!/bin/bash +x
        mkdir -p ${shellDir}
        ln -sfn ${shellDir} shell
        rm -rf shell.foo `ls -d shell.* | sed -e '/^${shellDir}\$/d' `
    """
```

With the way threading works here, a simple `++` might have functioned the same, but better safe than sorry.